# Probability that 2 sets of Playing Cards are random

Tags: probability

I have 2 sets of playing cards (648 cards in each set) supposedly selected at random from an unknown (assume infinite) number of packs of 52 cards. I suspect that they are not random and I want to know exactly how. I got the following result:

```
       Hearts Spades Diamonds Clubs  Total  M
 Set 1   194    146     143    165    648  162 
 Set 2   154    179     154    161    648  162
 Total   348    325     297    326  1,296  324
```

I want to know how to obtain the *p* value and effect size *d* of the following:

1. The significance of the individual selections to show, for example, that the Set 1 Hearts selection is significant.  Can this be done with a cumulative binomial calculation using BINOM.DIST in Excel?  What should I use as the expected probability .25?
2. Whether the individual sets are significant as a group of 4 or are they random.  Is this calculated with a Chi Squared Test (CHISQ.TEST on Excel) and what are the expected values with which to compare the results in the test?

   - mean values 162 OR
   - (row total* column total)/grand total
3. The probability of a correlation between the suit results in Set 1 and Set 2.
   For example, what is the probability that the higher value of Hearts in Set 1  is connected to the lower value Hearts in Set 2 or is it random?  Is it possible to combine two binomial calculations to evaluate the high value Hearts in Set 1 versus a low Hearts result in Set 2 or can this only be done with a Chi squared test?
4. How to calculate the connection between the 2 sets and are they significant as a group?
5. How can I calculate whether the low total number of Diamonds in the two sets is significant? I assume that it is a Binomial calculation based on the Mean.

Comment: The contrast between your questions 3 and 5 seem to hint that you are basing the questions on the observed data.  You are also asking a lot of questions overall. This will affect the significance adjustment if you want to reduce the chance of Type I errors.   The $194$ Hearts in the first set is fairly extreme, and that may affect some of your tests.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your advice.  It is a lot of questions.  I would much appreciate an answer to any single question as I believe that answers to Q.1 and 2 will give me a good sense of how to address the others.  Most of the results were expected, though the result in Q5 was not expected and I wish to know if the observed result is random or significant.